# unix file permissions

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, filesystems

File permissions in UNIX are frequently specified as an octal
number. Why is octal the preferred base for this purpose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the permissions are stored in a bit field, grouped in 3-bit chunks (eg **rwx**).

Octal is a natural way to describe them because you only need 1 octal digit to exactly represent any sequence of 3 binary digits.  (This is similar to why hexadecimal is used in programming -- since 1 hex digit can represent 4 binary digits, you only need 2 hex digits to describe 1 byte.  It boils down to the fact that 8 and 16 are powers of 2, so converting between octal and binary or hexadecimal and binary is really easy.)

These chunks are  **user** (aka owner), **group** and **others**.  Each chunk has three permissions to describe: **read**, **write**, and **execute**.

Hence the full set of permissions looks something like **rwxrwxrwx**, where each is a binary digit. So, for example, **110100100** in binary becomes **644** in octal, and you know that the first octal digit is for the *owner's* permissions, the second for the *group's* permissions, and the third for *everyone else*.

Comment: Traditionally *user*, group and other (not owner).  The alternate syntax for chmod would be "chmod u+x file", read as "allow the user to execute this file."

Comment: fixed.  pavium, ya beat me to the punch so i added the points i was going to make into your answer.  good job.

Comment: @~quack, thanks very much for the clarification and the comment. 'chunks' is a better word... makes more sense this way.

Answer (score 5):

There are three different classes specified by permissions on an object: Owner, group, and everyone else. Each of these classes has three independent permissions that can be set:  read, write, and execute.  This means each class has one of eight permission sets:

1. Execute
2. Write
3. Write/execute
4. Read
5. Read/execute
6. Read/write
7. Read/write/execute
8. No permissions

Since an octal digit takes one of eight different values (the numbers 0 through 7), you can represent any combination of read/write/execute with a single octal digit.

Internally, the computer stores permissions as a bit field.  So, for example, if you set permissions to 644, the computer might represent this as the binary number 110100100, or:

```
 110  |  100  |  100
 rw-  |  r--  |  r--
  6   |   4   |   4
Owner | Group | World
```

(Notice that binary 110 is equal to octal 6, and binary 100 is equal to octal 4).

Comment: the eight possible settings is true, but incidental.  we don't really consider all the different possibilities there -- the system sees it as a field of independent bits, and adds the bits together only when converting to an octal representation.

Comment: This is true, but I figured mapping bits might be a little tougher to understand for someone not already familiar with it.  I did add it below.